# Opposite function to array_combine /two arrays from an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I make two numeric arrays 
(one for keys one for values - the opposite of array combine)

Source info:

```
John => Physics,

Mary => Medicine,

Gary => Drama,
```

Output to

```
0=>Physics, 

1=>Medicine, 

2=>Drama
```

and

```
0=>John,

1=>Mary,

2=>Drama
```

It seems easy, but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on your associative array respectively.

---

If for whatever reason you *must* have numeric indices that start at 1 (as in your original question before any edits), you'll need to do a little more:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
array_unshift($keys, NULL);
unset($keys[0]);

$values = array_values($array);
array_unshift($values, NULL);
unset($values[0]);
```

Comment: I find this to be an elegant one-liner to reverse array_combine: `list($keys, $values) = [array_keys($array), array_values($array)]`. One question is, why do you have to reverse the combine, it maybe because you've combined it too early or have not provided yourself with the methods to retrieve the keys/values in an uncombined state which should be used by the method that gives it to you combined.

Comment: The answer seems correct at first hand, but: Is there any guarantee that the order of elements in the arrays generated by `array_keys()` and `array_values()` will match each other? I see no reference to it in the PHP documentation.